Mixed effect linear regression reversing $X$ and $Y$
Suppose I fit a mixed effect linear model with random intercept and slope with $Y$ as the response and $X_1, X_2, \dots$ as fixed effects. Random effects are subjected to ID and there are around $20$-$30$ repeated measures of $Y$. Can I do some linear transformation to the model such that we can use the old coefficients to predict $X_1$?
The reason that I don't want to fit a new model with $X_1$ as response and $Y$ as predictor is that I believe $Y$ is a function of $X$ by nature but $X$ is hard to observe sometimes. Also, if I ended up fitting a new model with $Y$ predict $X$, are the new coefficients the linear combinations of old coefficients?
